# How do I fix all menus and dialogs randomly becoming blank

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, menu-bar

Menu bar
[image: Menu bar]

Right click context menu in Chrome for example - (Note: the issue is not limited to chrome. it affects the context menu in every app) 
[image: Right click context menu in Chrome]

Either the logout or shut down dialog - I can't tell
[image: Either the logout or shut down dialog]

This happens randomly between once a month and once a week. The only way out is a hard reboot.

It would be nice to figure out how to permanently fix it.

macOS High Sierra
10.13.6
Apple MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.7 13" Touch/2018

Comment: What is the make and model of Mac that you are using? What is the version of macOS that you are running?

Comment: Uninstall chrome for a week (or however long it takes you to know this recurring issue is fixed)?

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with Chrome. The inclusion of the right click context menu is just an example.

Comment: Lots of other people have chrome installed when this happens. We have labs of hundreds of Macs where this only happens on the few with chrome and only occasionally. You might be right of course, but there's more than a small correlation between chrome and this. I don't disagree that once the system is borked - all apps break, but my suspicion is a third party app is doing the corruption / breaking. See my answer here for more context.https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/322581/menu-bar-and-right-click-menu-blank